# ResultSet error executing @Query in JPA Reposity, using nativeQuery = true

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a web application using:

- Spring Boot
- PostgreSQL
- JPA and Hibernate.

I have a table called `role` and another `page`. Among them there is a `many-to-many` table with ID's. What I'm trying to get is the list of pages that correspond to a role, so I'm trying to retrieve the list of pages from the id of the role and executing a query to bring the list. The problem is that I have an error in the `ResultSet` because it tells me that it does not find a column with the name `page_id`.

Example:
I have executed the query separately and this brings me results correctly.

```
select p.url from role_page rp, page p where rp.role_id = 6 and rp.page_id = p.page_id;
```

Output:
[Output of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Wlk.png)

Then I made a call to the function to get the list and check it to make sure I get results.

```
public void rolesAndPages(){
    List<Page> pages = pageRepository.findPagePerRole(6);
    for (Page page: pages
         ) {
        System.out.println(page.getUrl());
    }
}
```

And throws the error described above:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name page_id was not found in this ResultSet.
```

My Repository:

```
@Repository("pageRepository")
public interface PageRepository extends JpaRepository<Page, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select p.url from role_page rp, page p where rp.role_id = ?1 and rp.page_id = p.page_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Page> findPagePerRole(Integer id);
}
```

Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_role")
public class Role {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="pk_sequence",sequenceName="messagesounds_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="pk_sequence")
@Column(name="role_id")
private int id;
@Column(name="authority")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide a name")
private String authority;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "role_page", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "page_id"))
private Set<Page> pages;

public void setPages(Set<Page> pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}
public Set<Page> getPages() {
    return pages;
}

public Role() {}
public Role(String authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}
public Role(String authority, Set<Page> pages){
    this.authority = authority;
    this.pages = pages;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}
public void setAuthority(String authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}
}
```

Page.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "page")
public class Page {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "pk_sequence", sequenceName = "messagesounds_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk_sequence")
@Column(name = "page_id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "name_page")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide a name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "url")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an url")
private String url;
@Column(name = "description")
@NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide a description")
private String description;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "pages")
private Set<Role> roles;


public Page() {
}

public Page(String name_page) {
    this.name = name_page;
}

public Page(String name_page, Set<Role> roles) {
    this.name = name_page;
    this.roles = roles;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us you JPA mapping ?

Comment: @Zorglube You mean mapping to create many to many table, right?

Comment: yes your `role` and `page` object, and the JPA @nnoation they contain.

Comment: @Zorglube Done, i added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite explicite, you need to select page_id column to make it work, not only `p.url`.

Try this to retrieve every column of Page :

```
@Query(value = "select p.* from role_page rp, page p where rp.role_id = ?1 and rp.page_id = p.page_id", nativeQuery = true)
```

Or, this to retrieve every columns of tables Page and Role_Page :

```
@Query(value = "from role_page rp, page p where rp.role_id = ?1 and rp.page_id = p.page_id", nativeQuery = true)
```

The both queries should work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried :

```
@Query(value = "select p.url from role_page rp, page p where rp.id = ?1 and rp.id = p.id")
```